# SBS 2011 stuck applying computer settings

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

Hello we have an updated SBS 2011 server running in a VM on ESX.

Recently there was a power outage and when rebooting the server is stuck at "applying computer settings".

I have rebooted in safe mode and checked the logs but couldn't find something that said clearly there is an error.

- IPV6 is enabled in DHCP like always, no change to this (because there are many comments linked to disabled IPV6 adapters)
- When trying to check the DNS server in safe mode, the console doesnt connect to it. Not sure if it should in safe mode.
- When booting with the network adapter off, the server starts normally but then I cannot restart the interface in Windows. The network control panel just freezes.

I cannot revert to a backup because the backup failed without a notice since a few weeks.

Any ideas please, this is unfortunately fairly urgent.

Many thanks

Comment: Actually it seems the backup worked and it's a windowsimagebackup from this morning. Could I restore this with the above mentioned issues ?

Comment: On sbs2011/win2008r2, that windows can be long, could take 30m +.

Comment: i left it for an hour and it did nothing then I saw all the exchange services stuck in starting state.
I have successfully restored the backup image but it has the same issues...
Either there is an issue with the router distributing an ipv6 address event while disabled or something like that, or the issue has appeared with a previous windows update. I am talking about ipv6 because 70% of all messages linked to this say not to disable ipv6.

Comment: If you try to boot without the network cable, and plug it after if it come past that screen ? but yes I had that symptom often after windows update.

Answer (score 1):

So after reading pages of fixes that did nothing, it ended up being the ipv6 adapter's fault.

Nothing had changed in the ipv6 config, I don't know how this could happen. Anyway I restored the OS from backup as said above and tried to disable ipv6 completely following : 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2011/02/18/small-business-server-2011-slow-to-boot-and-several-services-fail-to-start/

This change made everything work again so I applied to the production server.
This is really odd.